# Finding the most frequent value in an array and then choosing the lowest value if there is a tie

Tags: java

I have the following program which looks up an array "a" and then output the value in the array which appears the most frequently. However one other condition that I would like to implement is that in the case of a tie where two different values appear an equal amount of times, the lowest value gets output.

So for the following code with an array:

```
int a[] = {34, 34, 20, 20, 15};
```

It outputs 34 however I want it to output 20 instead, since that is a lower value and appears just as many times in the array.

```
public class Arrays3 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a[] = {34, 34, 20, 20, 15};
        mode(a);
    }
    public static int mode(int[] a) {
        int[] counts = new int[101];
        int maxCount = 0;
        int maxKey = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            counts[a[i]]++;
            if(counts[a[i]] > maxCount) {
                maxCount = counts[a[i]];
                maxKey = a[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maxKey);
        return maxKey;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check against `maxKey` and then do something along the lines of:

```
 if(counts[a[i]] == maxCount && counts[a[i]] < maxKey) {
       maxKey = counts[a[i]];
 }
```

So that if there is ever a tie, the `maxKey` will be set to the smaller element. Then if `count[a[i]]` is ever greater than `maxCount`, `maxKey` will be overridden and become the element that occurs most often:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
     counts[a[i]]++;

     if(counts[a[i]] > maxCount) {
          maxCount = counts[a[i]];
          maxKey = a[i];
      }
      if(counts[a[i]] == maxCount && counts[a[i]] < maxKey) {
        maxKey = a[i];
      }
}
System.out.println(a[maxKey]);
```

***Output***

```
20
```

Answer (score 2):

An interesting solution (that I had fun writing) would be to first create a frequency `Map` by streaming your array and using `Collectors.groupingBy` with `Collectors.counting()`.

Then, we could stream that and use `Collectors.groupingBy` again to create a `Map<Long, SortedSet<Integer>>` (the key would be the frequency and the value would be the sorted set of values in your array with that frequency).

Finally, we can sort the `Map` so that the highest frequency comes first, and simply grab the lowest element from the `SortedSet`:

```
int[] a = {34, 34, 20, 20, 15};

var lowest = Arrays.stream(a)
                   .boxed()
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                   .entrySet()
                   .stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
                           Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new))))
                   .entrySet()
                   .stream()
                   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                   .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                   .mapToInt(TreeSet::first)
                   .findFirst();

lowest.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
20
```

Answer (score 0):

- You want to seek for the minimum value, so I suggest put `int maxKey = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`
- Then each time a better counts is found, we must compare to update the maxKey
  After all, the solution will look like this

  ```
  int[] counts = new int[101];
  int maxCount = 0;
  int maxKey = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

  for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      counts[a[i]]++;
      if(counts[a[i]] >= maxCount) {
          maxCount = counts[a[i]];
          if(a[i] < maxKey) maxKey = a[i];

      }
  }
  System.out.println(maxKey);
  return maxKey;
  ```

Have fun coding